# call an r object in loop

Tags: r, loops

I am new to R , and even if I searched for  a solution , I haven't found it yet. 
I want to call in a loop an plmtest object. 
I assign  the results from Lagrange Multiplier Test - (Breusch-Pagan) in plmtest5 and plmtest6, with the following  syntax in R:

```
for (i in (5:6))  assign(paste("plmtest",i,sep=""),
plmtest(eval(parse(text=paste('pool',i, sep=""))),type=c("bp")))
```

I want to show the results in a loop.
 I've tried

```
for (i in (5:6)) paste("plmtest",i,sep="")
```

and

```
for (i in (5:6)) print(paste("plmtest",i,sep=""))
```

with no results. 
The `plmtest5` and `plmtest6` works, but I want them in a loop.

How it can be done?

Comment: When you have a string that is the name of an object, you can use `get()` to access the object. (e.g., `x = 5; a = "x"; get(a)`). You'd be better off putting your `plmtest` objects in a list. Rather than `plmtest5 = ...` you'd have `plmtest_list[[5]] = ...`, then you can easily access `plmtest_list[[i]]` without messing with `paste` and `get`. This also has the advantage of letting you use `lapply` and `sapply` to do things to all the objects without writing out a loop.

Comment: that won''t answer your question put instead of using `paste("plmtest,i,sep="")`use `paste0('plmtest',i)`

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and suggestions, but I still can't figure it out how to put plmtest5 and plmtest6  in a list with loop. I was also considering using the  plyr package, but I am still try to learn and understand it. Thank you very much.

Comment: Replace `print(paste("plmtest",i,sep=""))` in your code with `print(get(paste("plmtest",i,sep="")))`, or to follow etienne's advice, `print(get(paste0("plmtest",i)))`. You just need to add `get()` around the string you construct.

Comment: Thank you very much Etienne and Gregor! That solved my problem!